# Deleting a row from a table. If an associated ID has more than 1 entry in another table, insert a value. Else insert null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following 3 tables:

```
Item Table
+---------+-------------+
| Item_ID | Location_ID |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 |          23 |
|       2 |          44 |
|       3 |          44 |
|       4 |          25 |
|       5 |          13 |
|       6 |          13 |
+---------+-------------+

Shipments Table
+-------------+------------------+----------------+
| Shipment_ID | Location_From_ID | Location_To_ID |
+-------------+------------------+----------------+
|           1 |               15 |             23 |
|           2 |               12 |             44 |
|           3 |                7 |             16 |
|           4 |               15 |             21 |
|           5 |               16 |             25 |
|           6 |               21 |             11 |
|           7 |               11 |             13 |
+-------------+------------------+----------------+

Item_Shipment_Link Table
+-------------+---------+
| Shipment_ID | Item_ID |
+-------------+---------+
|           1 |       1 |
|           2 |       2 |
|           2 |       3 |
|           3 |       4 |
|           4 |       5 |
|           4 |       6 |
|           5 |       4 |
|           6 |       5 |
|           7 |       5 |
|           7 |       6 |
+-------------+---------+
```

I am working on a procedure to delete a row from the Shipments Table.

When the shipment is deleted, the Location_ID(s) for the associated Item_ID(s) on the Item Table must be updated with the Location_From_ID value from the shipment. This is equivalent to placing the item back where it came from.

Any rows associated with the Shipment_ID being deleted must be removed from the Item_Shipment_Link Table as well.

**Example:** If Shipment_ID:5 is deleted, update the Location_ID for Item_ID:4 on the Item Table to 16. Also delete the entry for Shipment_ID:5 from the Item_Shipment_Link Table.

```
Item Table
+---------+-------------+
| Item_ID | Location_ID |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 |          23 |
|       2 |          44 |
|       3 |          44 |
|       4 |          16 |
|       5 |          13 |
|       6 |          13 |
+---------+-------------+

Shipments Table
+-------------+------------------+----------------+
| Shipment_ID | Location_From_ID | Location_To_ID |
+-------------+------------------+----------------+
|           1 |               15 |             23 |
|           2 |               12 |             44 |
|           3 |                7 |             16 |
|           4 |               15 |             21 |
|           6 |               21 |             11 |
|           7 |               11 |             13 |
+-------------+------------------+----------------+

Item_Shipment_Link Table
+-------------+---------+
| Shipment_ID | Item_ID |
+-------------+---------+
|           1 |       1 |
|           2 |       2 |
|           2 |       3 |
|           3 |       4 |
|           4 |       5 |
|           4 |       6 |
|           6 |       5 |
|           7 |       5 |
|           7 |       6 |
+-------------+---------+
```

If a shipment is deleted and the associated Item_ID(s) are not included in any other shipments, the Location_ID(s) for the associated Item_ID(s) on the Item Table must be set to NULL.

**Example:** If Shipment_ID:2 is deleted, update the Location_ID for Item_ID:2 and Item_ID:3 on the Item Table to NULL. Also delete the entries for Shipment_ID:2 from the Item_Shipment_Link Table.

```
Item Table
+---------+-------------+
| Item_ID | Location_ID |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 |          23 |
|       2 |        NULL |
|       3 |        NULL |
|       4 |          25 |
|       5 |          13 |
|       6 |          13 |
+---------+-------------+

Shipments Table
+-------------+------------------+----------------+
| Shipment_ID | Location_From_ID | Location_To_ID |
+-------------+------------------+----------------+
|           1 |               15 |             23 |
|           3 |                7 |             16 |
|           4 |               15 |             21 |
|           5 |               16 |             25 |
|           6 |               21 |             11 |
|           7 |               11 |             13 |
+-------------+------------------+----------------+

Item_Shipment_Link Table
+-------------+---------+
| Shipment_ID | Item_ID |
+-------------+---------+
|           1 |       1 |
|           3 |       4 |
|           4 |       5 |
|           4 |       6 |
|           5 |       4 |
|           6 |       5 |
|           7 |       5 |
|           7 |       6 |
+-------------+---------+
```

It is possible for a shipment to contain some items that have been in previous shipments, and some items that have not been in any previous shipments.

**Example:** If Shipment_ID:7 is deleted, update the Location_ID for Item_ID:5 on the Item Table to 11. Update the Location_ID for Item_ID:6 on the Item Table to NULL. Also delete the entries for Shipment_ID:7 from the Item_Shipment_Link Table.

```
Item Table
+---------+-------------+
| Item_ID | Location_ID |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 |          23 |
|       2 |          44 |
|       3 |          44 |
|       4 |          25 |
|       5 |          11 |
|       6 |        NULL |
+---------+-------------+

Shipments Table
+-------------+------------------+----------------+
| Shipment_ID | Location_From_ID | Location_To_ID |
+-------------+------------------+----------------+
|           1 |               15 |             23 |
|           2 |               12 |             44 |
|           3 |                7 |             16 |
|           4 |               15 |             21 |
|           5 |               16 |             25 |
|           6 |               21 |             11 |
+-------------+------------------+----------------+

Item_Shipment_Link Table
+-------------+---------+
| Shipment_ID | Item_ID |
+-------------+---------+
|           1 |       1 |
|           2 |       2 |
|           2 |       3 |
|           3 |       4 |
|           4 |       5 |
|           4 |       6 |
|           5 |       4 |
|           6 |       5 |
+-------------+---------+
```

**Note:** It does not matter if an Item_ID is associated with shipments that occurred before or after the Shipment_ID being deleted. The application will only allow you to delete the most recent shipment associated with an Item_ID, so if an Item_ID has entries in the Item_Shipment_Link Table they are guaranteed to have occurred prior to the shipment being deleted.

Essentially, I need to get each Item_ID associated with the Shipment_ID that is being deleted and then check if each Item_ID has more than 1 entry in the Item_Shipment_Link Table. If it has more than 1 entry, set its Location_ID on the Item Table to the Location_From_ID of the shipment that is being deleted. If it has only 1 entry, set its Location_ID on the Item Table to NULL.

This is the pseudo code for what I am trying to accomplish:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ExampleProcedure (@Shipment_ID INT)

DECLARE @OLD_Location_From_ID INT

SET @OLD_Location_From_ID = 
(SELECT Location_From_ID FROM Shipments WHERE Shipment_ID = @Shipment_ID)

FOR (each Item_ID associated with @Shipment_ID on the Item_Shipment_Link Table)
    IF (Item_ID has more than 1 entry in the Item_Shipment_Link Table)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE i
            SET i.Location_ID = @OLD_Location_From_ID
            FROM Item i
            JOIN Item_Shipment_Link l ON i.Item_ID = l.Item_ID
            WHERE l.Shipment_ID = @Shipment_ID
        END
    ELSE (Item_ID has only 1 entry in the Item_Shipment_Link Table)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE i
            SET i.Location_ID = NULL
            FROM Item i
            JOIN Item_Shipment_Link l ON i.Item_ID = l.Item_ID
            WHERE l.Shipment_ID = @Shipment_ID
        END

DELETE Item_Shipment_Link
WHERE Shipment_ID = @Shipment_ID

DELETE Shipments
WHERE Shipment_ID = @Shipment_ID
```

Comment: Previous experience... hard deletes are scary. Why don't you have a `bit` on the table, `IsDeleted`? Then you can code per the soft deletes. If not, then why not use a `trigger` to do what you want?

Comment: @WEI_DBA Previous experience, Never deleting + triggers doesn't scale.

Comment: Ponder using `case when ( select Count( 42 ) from Item_Shipment_Link as ISL2 where ISL2.Item_Id = S.Item_Id ) > 1 then S.Location_From_Id else NULL end` as a way to get the new value of `Location_Id` inside a query. Try that in a `select` that joins the three tables: `Item as I`, `Shipments as S` and `Item_Shipment_Link as ISL`. Once you are getting the values you want you can change it to an `update` that provides as set-based solution rather than [RBAR](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/).